# How to make value scale up at same rate as user keypress in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, keypress, game-development

I'm currently trying to make an AI move smoothly when going up and down and I'm struggling to find something or a way to replicate the way the player controlled Game Object move.

 When my code runs currently, the Enemy AI appears to jump up and down as if it were vibrating in order to match the other game Objects y component. I understand that this happens because it tracks it makes those micro adjustments in order to match the y component, so I'm trying to find a way to simulate the scale at which a users keypress occurs, but within my AI script.

```
    #region Public Variables
    #endregion
    #region Inspector Variables
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 ballPos;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ballRef;
    #endregion
    #region Private Variable

    #endregion
    #region Components
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    #endregion
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    } //Onstartup executes



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        UpdateBallPos();
        MoveAI();
    }


    #region Methods
    private void MoveAI()
    {

        if (ballPos.y > transform.position.y)
        {


            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, //artificially made speed scale// * moveSpeed);
        }

        else if (ballPos.y + 0.2 > transform.position.y || ballPos.y - 0.2 > transform.position.y)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, //artifically made speed scale// -moveSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateBallPos()
    {
        ballPos = new Vector2(ballRef.transform.position.x, ballRef.transform.position.y);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When a user presses a button referring to the Input manager, rather than jumping straight to the maximum (1), it scales quickly to simulate a smooth motion.
My player script looks like this

```
    #region Public Variables
    #endregion
    #region Inspector Variables
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    #endregion
    #region Private Variables
    private float yInput;
    #endregion
    #region Components
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    #endregion

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    } //Onstartup executes

    private void Update()
    {
        GetMoveInput();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    #region Methods
    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, yInput * moveSpeed);
    }

    private void GetMoveInput()
    {
        yInput = Input.GetAxis("PlayerLeft");
    }
    #endregion
```

I'm trying to find something which can replace the "yInput" in the player script and use that in my AI script.
I thought I might be able to simulate sending a keypress within my script but there doesn't seem to be one, plus it would create the issue of users potentially pressing that button and sending a real keypress.

I apologise about the explanation, I'm not sure how else to say it and I've been trying to figure something out for a while. Any help at all is appreciated and any advice for my code in general would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly understand your goal, but this seems either a case for [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (or "lerp"), for straight-up [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) usage or for a mix of both. Plus, the code you posted kind of looks like Pong :)

If you need to track and follow an object, moving frame-by-frame via `deltaTime`, by "lerping" or by both can be a good starting point, and can easily evolve into more complex behaviours or can be "released as is", if you're fine with the end result.
In short and in their simplest form, `Time.deltaTime` is the fraction of time that passed between two frames in your main loop, while "Linear interpolation" means that, given two points "A" and "B", you're able to get any "N" point between those two.

You can use one, the other or a mix of both in Unity to smoothly move an object towards a specific destination, rather than by teleporting it or moving it at a constant speed.

Here's an untested snippet to hopefully set you in the right direction.
It uses [normalized vectors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html), since you're using velocities, as using raw `Vector2`s off the bat will likely result in weird or near-instant movements.
It's also using vectors to give you a general idea of how lerping works, but it can be done only on the `y` axis too, by using [`Mathf.lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) rather than [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

```
private void MoveAI()
{
    Vector3 from = transform.position; //This is your point "A"
    Vector3 to = ballPos; //This is your point "B"
    to.x = from.x; // You're interested in finding the "N" offset on the y axis
    to.z = from.z;
    Vector3 offset = Vector3.Lerp(from.normalized, to.normalized, moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //using fixedDeltaTime because the method is called from FixedUpdate
    rb.velocity = offset;
}
```

As for side notes on your code and how I wrote the snippet:

- Avoid creating vectors with `new` if you can, especially when it's done each frame/each physics-update-tick. It's not a problem when you're experimenting, but it can become an unwanted overhead down the line.
- Avoid introducing hard-coded constants when checking for ranges unless it's supposed to be by design. I'm talking about the 0.2 offset you're adding and removing in your AI script. If you need to check for "deadzones", [Mathf.epsilon](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html), used either raw or with multipliers, will most likely yield better and more reliable results
- Always factor in `Time.deltaTime`/`Time.fixedDeltaTime` if you're doing something to GameObjects each frame. In short words, it allows you to easily keep consistency between your game logic and the framerate, preventing odd behaviors when the latter is above or below the targeted one